How to handle a iframe which is available in another iframe
There is a iframe which is embedded in another iframe in a page. I need to do action in elements which is present in child iframe and exactly here facing an error to perform action on element.
Rough html is as follows:
  <html> 
<body> 
<iframe src="https://..."> 
<iframe src="htpps://...">
 <input type='text' id='search' > 
<button>Click Me></button> 
</iframe> 
</iframe> 
</body>
 </html>

I used the following approach to handle it but it was unsuccessful: capturing the first iframe using frameLocator and storing it in a frame variable, and using frame variable I tried to capture another iframe.
const frame= await this.page.frameLocator("//iframe[contains(@id,'easyXDM_default')]")
await frame.frameLocator("//iframe[@src='\url of the iframe site\']").fill("#search",'bnma')

Error:
 TypeError: iframe.frameLocator(...).fill is not a function


Handling nested iframes by index is a simple and alternate way if you wish to consider
Type 1
test('nested iframe test by index', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("...");
    const frames = page.frames();
    
    // Locate the inner iframe element
    const innerIframe = frames[2];
    await innerIframe.getByText("Click Me").click();
});

Type 2
test('nested iframe test by index', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("...");
    const frames = page.frames();
    
    const outerIframe = frame[1];
    const innerIframe = outerIframe.frameLocator('#frame2'); 
    
    await innerIframe.getByText("Click Me").click();
});


Try using a locator first, then .fill(). Here's a minimal, reproducible example. First, create 3 HTML files.
page1.html
<iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>

page2.html
<iframe src="page3.html"></iframe>

page3.html
<input type="text" id="search">
<button>Click Me</button> 

Then write a test:
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8000/page1.html");
  const frame1 = page.frameLocator('iframe[src="page2.html"]');
  const frame2 = frame1.frameLocator('iframe[src="page3.html"]');
  await frame2.locator("#search").fill("bnma");
  await frame2.getByRole("button", {name: "Click Me"}).focus();
  await page.screenshot({path: "proof.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Run a web server on port 8000 with python -m http.server, php -S localhost:8000 or any other handy web server to serve the HTML files. Then run the Playwright script with node your-script.js and open proof.png to see the successful manipulation of the inner frame:

You can convert this to a test as follows (a snapshot test isn't necessarily appropriate here, just used for proving that it works):
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test("fills nested iframe", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8000/page1.html");
  const frame1 = page.frameLocator('iframe[src="page2.html"]');
  const frame2 = frame1.frameLocator('iframe[src="page3.html"]');
  await frame2.locator("#search").fill("bnma");
  await frame2.getByRole("button", {name: "Click Me"}).focus();
  await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot();
});

See Locating an element in any iframe using Playwright for a solution for arbitrarily nested frames.
